# django call a view with optional argument

Tags: python, django, url, view, reverse

I wrote a middleware that prevents from users in certain group to access a view,
If a user without permission tries to access the page it should redirect him to a login with a message (saying he has no permissions).

I thought to do it like that:
have a login view:

```
def login_view(request, permission=None):
```

and in the middleware:

```
class ManagerRequiredMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
def process_request(self, request):
    assert hasattr(request, 'user')
    if not request.user.groups.filter(name='Manager').exists():
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS) and not any(m.match(path) for m in MANAGER_URLS):
            print('no manager')
            next = request.path_info
            #return redirect('/login/?next=%s' % next, permission=True)
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login', kwargs={'permission': True}))
            return redirect('/login/?next=%s' % next)
```

as you can see I tried multiple things. I want to keep the where he tried to access (to redirect him after login), but also want to call login_view with the permission flag on so I can display the right message.

I don't want this argument to be visible in the URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator, it will automatically redirect user after login. For custom permission you can use `permission_required` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)

Comment: I know but I'm using middleware because most of the pages required login, but this is another measure because there are a few kinds of users.